# How can List (MutableSequence) be presented in UML class diagram?

Tags: python, uml

I am curious, since I cannot find any information related to this, but how can a piece of code like the one below, be represented in a UML Class Diagram?

Is it just an inheritance? 
What about these Python Special Methods/Symbols that `__something__`.

```
from collections.abc import MutableSequence

class Inventory(MutableSequence):

    def __init__(self, *items): 
        self.items = list()
        self.items.extend(items)

    def __setitem__(self, index, value): 
        self.items[index] = value

    def __getitem__(self, index): 
        return self.items[index]

    def __len__(self): 
        return len(self.items)

    def __delitem__(self, index): 
        del self.items[index]

    def insert(self, index, value): 
        self.items.insert(index, value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagram could look like

[image]

Operations for Python can just be noted as per their original name (with the underscores). I left away the first `self` parameter as it is mandatory for Python class operations. A code generator can create these with ease. If you would like to add static operations in the class you could stereotype them (e.g. with `<<static>>` or the like; you could make a Python profile). Since anything is untyped in Python I used `var` as type. That would be a convention.

In order to show the import location you could add a package structure showing the namespace for `MutableSequence`. Anything along those lines:

[image]

Comment: WOW! This is interesting. Please share more, I'd love to better understand. I have never seen something like this.

Comment: Like what of the above?

Comment: Is this correctly by the standards of UML? Because else it looks kind of too Pythonic?

Comment: I can't tell about the `from` under-titles since this is made by Enterprise Architect. I would not consider it wrong, though. Anyhow, this is native UML.